# What is the difference between constructor parameters and member variables in Kotlin classes?

Tags: android-studio, class, kotlin, parameters, member-variables

I discovered that both **constructor parameters** and **member variables** behave almost the same way.

The only difference is that: the `noOfSides` cannot be changed inside `class Square`, whereas `noOfSideVar` can be changed inside the `class Square`

**Code that I have written:**

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var square1 = Square(4)
    println("Parameter form: ${square1.noOfSides}")
    println("Variable form: ${square1.noOfSideVar}")

    square1.noOfSides = 10
    square1.noOfSideVar = 50

    println("New Parameter form: ${square1.noOfSides}")
    println("New Variable form: ${square1.noOfSideVar}")

}

open class Polygon(var noOfSides: Int)

class Square(noOfSides: Int) : Polygon(noOfSides) {

    var noOfSideVar = 7
    fun area(): Int {
        return noOfSides * noOfSides
    }

}
```

**The output of the above code:**

```kotlin
Parameter form: 4
Variable form: 7
New Parameter form: 10
New Variable form: 50

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I am having any sort of misconception, please clear it.
I know this is a fundamental question but I am quite confused as a beginner.

Comment: Are you aware that when printing `println("Parameter form: ${square1.noOfSides}")`, you are not actually accessing the constructor parameter (it is impossible to do that from `main`)? You're just accessing the member variable `noOfSides` that `Square` inherits from `Polygon`.

Comment: @Sweeper `noOfSides` is a parameter for `Polygon` . So, I think I am accessing the **inherited parameter**. What do you say about this? Please point out where I am going wrong.

Comment: It is a parameter for `Polygon`, but it is _also_ a member variable (aka _property_). See that `var` prefix? Are you aware of what it means?

Comment: @Sweeper not have knowledge of that actually. SO what is the difference

Comment: The point is: both `noOfSides` and `noOfSideVar` in your example are member variables and this is why you don't see a difference between them.

Comment: @broot What if I remove var/val which is before `noOfSides`. how will the code be affected? Also if you can classify what should I learn so that this confusion of mine no longer persists I would be grateful. @Sweeper

Comment: You can really check it by yourself. If you remove `var` then as a result you will remove `noOfSides` property and it won't be available in both `main()` and `area()` functions. This syntax is described here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors , starting from: "Kotlin has a concise syntax for ..."